# IOS app not recognizing accelerometer data or text input

Tags: ios, objective-c

This code is not giving me any output or even setting up the accelerometer it seems.  I am first and foremost trying to get the device to recognize the accelerometer and the thresh input.  It is a simple accelerometer app where I can set up a thresh hold variable where I can then compare some values from previous and current accelerometer output.  The thresh input is a simple text box for input.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    //set up variables for switch and BOOL variables
    BOOL isStarted;
    BOOL switchX;
    BOOL switchY;
    BOOL switchZ;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)startSensor:(id)sender{

    //start with displaying the values...then move onto the just flash method
    //set up the accelerometer function within the button press
    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
        [self showAccelerationdata:accelerometerData.acceleration];
        //print statements for future debugging.  only in the log files though
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    currentAccelx = 0;
    currentAccely = 0;
    currentAccelz = 0;

    previousAccelx = 0;
    previousAccely = 0;
    previousAccelz = 0;

    //set up class for movement controls
    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = .1;
}

-(IBAction)checkSwitchx:(UISwitch *)sender{
    if (sender.on){
        switchX = TRUE;
    }
    else{
        switchX = FALSE;
    }
}

-(IBAction)checkSwitchy:(UISwitch *)sender{
    if (sender.on){
        switchY = TRUE;
    }
    else{
        switchY = FALSE;
    }
}

-(IBAction)checkSwitchz:(UISwitch *)sender{
    if (sender.on){
        switchZ = TRUE;
    }
    else{
        switchZ = FALSE;
    }
}

-(void)showAccelerationdata:(CMAcceleration)acceleration
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if ([thresh.text length] == 0){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"numbers are blank!" message:@"Please enter numbers!"
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok!" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else{
        threshold = [thresh.text floatValue];
        NSLog(@"%@", thresh);
    }
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you wired up your UI to call your `startSensor` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the code where you set self.motionManager.
If you don't actually create a CMMotionManager, you are sending messages to nil in the startSensor: method, and you will observe that no accelerometer callbacks are executed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not set up my CMMotionManager correctly it seems.  After I looked at my setup it was pretty straight-forward on how to get everything to display correctly.